# How to use patch_internal

Tags: eve

In my app I have a Hook that should update a field in a resource:
In another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347713/acessing-app-eve-object-from-hook-callbacks) someone used the patch_internal method, but I did not understand, how.

```
from my_application import app
from eve.methods.patch import patch_internal

def my_hook(...):
    with app.test_request_context():
        patch_internal("my_resource", payload={"bar": "bar_value"}, lookup={"foo": "foo_value"})
```

I tried to use `PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION = False` in `settings.py`.

Depending on the way I try it, I get either

- a 404 for the original request, that triggered the hook in the first place,
- or an AssertionError:

.

```
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in wsgi_app
    ctx.auto_pop(error)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 374, in auto_pop
    self.pop(exc)
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 357, in pop
% (rv, self)
AssertionError: Popped wrong request context.
(<RequestContext 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/' [GET] of eve> instead of <RequestContext 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/my_endpoint' [GET] of eve>)
```

My question is:

What are the proper parameters for patch_internal? 
How do I tell Eve, which item I want to change?

Comment: To clarify: `foo` is `unique` and `required` (but I also tried the lookup with '_id: ObjectId(...)` , and the item I want to change does exist in the database,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a trivial example that should work:

```
from eve import Eve
from eve.methods.patch import patch_internal


app = Eve()

def my_hook(*args):
    with app.test_request_context():
        payload = {"bar": "bar_value"}
        lookup = {"_id": "4f71e038c88e201118000002"}
        patch_internal("my_resource", payload, **lookup)


# this is rather stupid. We're going to patch the same document on *every* GET request, but you get the point
app.on_post_GET += my_hook


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Or you could check the [patch internal test](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/blob/master/eve/tests/methods/patch.py#L183-L194) for a slightly more articulate example. Also here is a good [post_internal example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319716/using-eves-db-layer-without-http/25493169#25493169). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the problem was python-related, not eve-related with `**lookup`

Comment: @nicola, why use `test_request_context` over `request_context`?